# Tweak cmd.exe to display the folder path

Tags: command-line

I want to tweak the cmd.exe to display the long names into the short one's like say example 
`C:\Documents and Settings\` into `C:\DOCUM~1`

I know that it can done with `command.exe` , But it doesn't have the auto complete feature.

Is there any tweaks or tools to display the path like that using cmd.exe ?

Comment: Do you mean the actual prompt, or the file listings?

Comment: Actual Prompt , not the dir/file listing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible, see this article that discusses every possible trick to do with the prompt of cmd.exe:

[A better PROMPT for CMD.EXE or Cool Prompt Environment Variables and a nice transparent multi-prompt](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterPROMPTForCMDEXEOrCoolPromptEnvironmentVariablesAndANiceTransparentMultiprompt.aspx)

As noted here, there are many cmd replacement shells which are more flexible.

Comment: I too think so , its not possible with cmd.exe

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean command.com, not command.exe.

There is no way to get the short filenames in cmd.exe in my opinion.

You could use T[**akeCommand Console LE**](http://www.jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm). It's free and a replacement for cmd.exe with a lot of extra features. It supports autocompletion (with the TAB key) and short filenames.

They explain about it in the helpfile:

> On LFN drives, TCC will search for and
>   display long filenames during filename
>   completion. If you want to search for
>   8.3 short filenames (SFNs), press Ctrl-A before you start using filename
>   completion. This allows you to use
>   filename completion on LFN drives with
>   applications that do not support long
>   filenames. The LFNToggle directive can
>   be used to change the keystroke
>   assigned to this feature.
>
> You can press Ctrl-A at any time prior
>   to beginning filename completion. The
>   switch to SFN format remains is in
>   effect for the remainder of the
>   current command line. When TCC begins
>   a new command line it returns to long
>   filename format until you press Ctrl-A
>   again.
>
> You can also press Ctrl-A just after a
>   filename is displayed, and the name
>   will be converted to short filename
>   format. However, this feature only
>   affects the most recently entered file
>   or directory name (the part between
>   the cursor and the last backslash []
>   on the command line), and any
>   subsequent entries. It will not
>   automatically convert all the parts of
>   a previously entered path.
>
> Ctrl-A toggles the filename completion
>   mode, so you can switch back and forth
>   between long and short filename
>   displays by pressing Ctrl-A each time
>   you want to change modes.

Comment: I tried it , but still it everytime i can't press CTRL+A to change the directory name.

Comment: Works fine for me. With the TAB key, select a directory with a long filename (\Program Files\ for instance). Press CTRL+A and the shortname is displayed instead.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done. The output of `help prompt` gives a list of what can be done:

```
C:\>HELP PROMPT
Changes the cmd.exe command prompt.
```

PROMPT [text]

text    Specifies a new command prompt.

Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special codes:

$A   & (Ampersand)
  $B   | (pipe)
  $C   ( (Left parenthesis)
  $D   Current date
  $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
  $F   ) (Right parenthesis)
  $G   > (greater-than sign)
  $H   Backspace (erases previous character)
  $L   < (less-than sign)
  $N   Current drive
  $P   Current drive and path
  $Q   = (equal sign)
  $S     (space)
  $T   Current time
  $V   Windows version number
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed
  $$   $ (dollar sign)

If Command Extensions are enabled the PROMPT command supports
the following additional formatting characters:

$+   zero or more plus sign (+) characters depending upon the
       depth of the PUSHD directory stack, one character for each
       level pushed.

$M   Displays the remote name associated with the current drive
       letter or the empty string if current drive is not a network
       drive.

It is possible to get this information in other CMD contexts, using the `%~` syntax in `call` and `for`. For example, consider this script:

```
@ECHO OFF
call :X "%CD%"
goto :EOF
```

:X
echo %1
echo %~s1

Output is:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings"
C:\DOCUME~1
```

See `call /?` and `for /?` for details.

It could come as no surprise that this is trivial in PowerShell. In PowerShell, the prompt doesn't have its own special syntax; it's a perfectly normal function. You can use

```
Get-ShortPath $PWD
```

Answer (score 0):

To force short 8.3 filenames, use the dir command with the inverted /N option, like so:

```
dir /-N
```

Also I use [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) a console enhancement, supports auto-complete too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a found a way to do this:

First run (Double percents in batch files):

```
@for /f "delims=" %a in ('cd') do @set "short=%~sa"
```

Then use:

```
prompt %short%$G
```